# The use of antimatter being a solution to the Fermi Paradox

Tags: antimatter, fermi-paradox

While there are many proposed solutions to the Fermi Paradox, one option in particular stood out to me as a likely candidate: antimatter.

It's no secret that antimatter is one of the most dangerous substances that exists: it must be contained or else it goes boom.

Given that this invites disaster, it led me to propose it as a solution to the Fermi Paradox: an accident with the stored antimatter that causes an explosion comparable to a large asteroid impact.

No security system is perfect, and with Murphy's law, it's only a matter of time before something happens, and all that antimatter destroys the planet it's on.

With that said, how viable a solution to the Fermi Paradox is this?

As for the world I'm proposing, aliens are on a quest to stop civilizations from developing antimatter technology, as their own world was destroyed by using antimatter. They've come to Earth to stop humanity from developing antimatter before humanity destroys itself like all the other races these aliens have encountered.

Comment: Is this set in a world you're building? If so, it would be good to add information about that - if it's not, the question would likely be off-topic for Worldbuilding.

Comment: This is nothing but a speculation on one of the possible facets of [Robin Hanson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hanson)'s [Great Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Filter) hypothesis. (The general Great Filter hypothesis is that *something* must filter out the vast majority of civilizations before they reach the stage where they are able to colonize the Galaxy, so that the probability of a civilization reaching that stage is very very small.)

Comment: Antimatter is not a good one. Some more plausible candidates would be things like global warming, bio-weapons, nukes, or rouge AIs.  You can get these in world killing doses well before becoming a space bound civilization.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjtOGPJ0URM), and then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fQkVqno-uI).

Comment: The Fermi paradox doesn't need solving. Just use less ludicrously optimistic values in the drake equation, and voila.

Comment: Anti-matter is only dangerous if you have large enough amount together in one place. What is the reason for any civilizations for doing that? We did not. So far we have no reason to create and store a large amount. Nuclear bombs, hydrogen bombs, errand asteroid crashing down are far more dangerous.

Answer (score 14):

## Not Very

Antimatter is [ludicrously expensive](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/212_fall2003.web.dir/tyler_freeman/modern.htm#:%7E:text=Creating%20Antimatter%3A,from%201.5%20to%2015%20nanograms) to make, both in terms of energy and equipment.  There is no reason to expect this to change dramatically.  Antimatter is mostly useful as a means of maximally-dense energy storage, so keeping enough of it on a planet to destroy that planet would

1. Be an excellent sign of species stupidity, since well before anyone could make enough antimatter to be a threat to the planet, people were posting on world network forums about the dangers of antimatter, and
2. Be an enormous waste of a valuable resource.  Valuable resources do not generally adhere to the "all your eggs in one basket" philosophy.

Despite its portrayal in science fiction, antimatter is not remotely one of the most dangerous substances that exists.  It reacts with matter to annihilate an equal mass to its own, as dictated by its own, and releases a commensurate amount of energy, but a quarter-kilogram of antimatter is needed to replicate a city-killing hydrogen bomb.  You would need a hundred million times as much to replicate, for example, the [Chicxulub event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater) that ended the dinosaurs.  Twenty five thousand tonnes of antimatter would, at its minimal estimated cost, require 6.25 quadrillion dollars' worth of electricity at current rates.

All of this makes antimatter *extremely* unlikely to be a principal candidate for the Great Filter.

---

Edit: The minimal projected cost of producing antimatter at current energy rates is $2.5M/gram, based on the (optimistic) assumption of perfect conversion of energy to antimatter.

Comment: In terms of what I mean by antimatter being an also-ran in terms of danger, 250 grams of [botulism toxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulinum_toxin) is enough to kill everyone on earth, and can be produced far more cheaply.  Distribution is still a problem, but antimatter is just a slightly more effective nuke, not a doomsday material.

Comment: "*Keeping enough of it on a planet to destroy that planet would be an excellent sign of species stupidity.*" <looks at nuclear arsenal> <looks at camera>

Comment: If "destroying" a planet means overcoming the gravity that binds it together, the antimatter needed to destroy Earth would have a mass in the trillions of tonnes, so the current cost would be septillions of dollars. That number's so big my spellcheck underlines it.

Comment: @jdunlop We can treat botulism. Even untreated, [botulism is "only" 50% fatal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulism#Treatment). Whereas there's no known treatment for an anti-matter explosion. I agree it is just a more effective nuke... or less, there's less long-term fallout.

Comment: @J.G. You are thinking of hypothetical negative matter which has negative mass. Gravitational behaviour isn't reversed for anti-matter. Or at least, we don't know conclusively how it behaves but most physicists believe it behaves like normal because it seems to have positive mass. That's why you never see anyone talk about making hover vehicles with anti-matter.

Comment: @DKNguyen [I *am* a physicist with expertise on the particle physics of gravity](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/12277/), and made no such mistake. Gravitational disassembly of Earth would require far more mass. I was referring to how much energy has to be added [to overcome Earth's gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy#Derivation_for_a_uniform_sphere), and how much mass it has no matter where it comes from

Comment: @J.G. Oh were you talking about an old ordinary blast that would just blast the Earth apart Death Star style? I thought you were talking about nullifying the force of gravity itself.

Comment: @DKNguyen For comparison, if the energy came from the Sun instead with a Dyson swarm, it'd take hours.

Comment: @J.G. Where is the line drawn between gravitational disassembly anyways? Is it where the bits of planet are blasted so far apart they can never coalesce into the same planet again? Because I imagine blasting it enough so that everything more or less falls back into itself more or less immediately or on geologic time scales would pretty much get the job done and look the same to anyone with a human lifespan.

Comment: @DKNguyen It comes down to what you want to do. If all you care about is killing any life on the planet, temporarily raising the whole surface to 500 K is more than sufficient.

Comment: @J.G. I'm still talking about actually "destroying a planet". I guess it depends on whether you still consider it the same planet just because it's made from the same matter, even if hopelessly re-arranged.

Comment: @DKNguyen If you overcome GPE, the particles will be too far apart to coalesce again, just as when a rocket leaves Earth it doesn't have to come back. Less would just remove part from the outside.

Answer (score 6):

### The main problem with this is it does not align with the Non-Exclusivity Principle for the Fermi Paradox

**What you have just identified is a 'Great Filter' 'ahead' of us**. Generally speaking, a 'Great Filter' is something that is certain to happen that severely reduces the factors that multiply the possible number of civilisations.

So, indeed Nuclear War, rampant A.I., incurable virus, huge asteroid impacts and gamma ray bursts are classified as Great Filters as they are possible to cause extinction of Technologically Intelligent Life, and the Great Filter is 'ahead' of us because it hasn't happened to 'us' yet, rather than behind us (such as forming multicellular life, which from all evidence appears very unlikely).

However, now we get to the Non-Exclusivity Principle. This is the principle that *whatever happens, it must happen certainly to all Civilisations with no exceptions*.

This is because of the enormous quantity of planets that could support life in the Universe (not just our galaxy) any one could produce evidence we could detect. So let's say there's a 0.0001% chance of a Civilisation NOT dying out due to Antimatter, that should **still leave several thousand extraterrestrial civilisations in our Galaxy alone, and several billion in the Universe**.

And further, we are very close to building a Von-Neumann probe of our own with our limited technology. This indicates it is *possible to build one without the use of Anti-Matter at all*, so there is likely to be many Civilisations that should have already done this without going through your Great Filter.

Unfortunately, for me **the evidence is pointing to the fact that we are the first** - because very soon (perhaps in the next couple of decades) it is possible to build a self-replicating probe ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds highly unlikely to me. Lets gather together a few kg of antimatter on a densely populated planet for some unspecified reason. What could go wrong? I can't think of any reason why they would be so stupid. Not only that but as a solution to the Fermi paradox every advanced civilisation appears to have the same crazy plan.

So no, it is not a reasonable solution to the Fermi paradox.

Answer (score 2):

Quick back of the envelop calculation, how much anti-matter are we talking about?

A matter-antimatter reaction is perfect annihilation. How much energy you get from equal amounts of matter and antimatter is $E = mc^2$. How much mass you need to get a certain energy is $m = \frac{E}{c^2}$.

If by "an explosion comparable to a large asteroid impact" we assume something on the scale of [Chicxulub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater). [Estimates (see 4.1)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1403/1403.6391.pdf) put it at $10^{24}J$ to $5\times 10^{25}J$. I'll use the lowest estimate to give this the best possible chance of working. Plugging $10^{24} J$ in as $E$ gives 11000 tonnes. Half of that is matter, half anti-matter. 5500 tonnes of anti-matter.

5500 tonnes is A LOT of antimatter to have in one place or even on one planet.

While one might think of reasons an advanced civilization needs 5500 tonnes of anti-matter in total, I can't think of why they need to collect it all in one place. Nor why every advanced civilization will eventually collect 30 blue whales worth of anti-matter together and then accidentally blow it up.

Comment: The linked page to Chicxulub says it was between 1.3e24 and 5.8e25 J, which is larger than the value you quote by an order of magnitude or two. This would increase the mass by an order of magnitude or two.

Comment: @BBeast I was using the number on my favorite page, [Orders of magnitude (energy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)#1018_to_1023_J). Going to [the linked paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1403/1403.6391.pdf), section 4.1 has 5e23 as the lowest end of the estimate.

Comment: Ah, that page. A useful page. But yes, following references seems to be better than trusting entirely on Wikipedia in this case. Reading the paper you linked, it excludes Model 1 (which had 5e23 J) as not being valid at Chicxulub energy scales. 1e24 J (as you have edited) is a decent lower bound for a back of the envelope calculation.